# SQL - Calculate active minutes per month per device

Tags: sql, datetime, distinct

I am seeking some input/suggestions on ways that I could calculate the active number of minutes per month, as a percentage, of a specific device.

My table has columns:

```
device_id      |     build_date
A4207B23-C984     2015-05-28 07:33:29.6980000 -04:00
76D53271-FD34     2015-05-29 15:51:19.0000000 -04:00
```

I would like to generate a report each month showing the percentage of the month that a device was active and "building."  Any build in a single minute could be counted as being active, but I need to account for varying days of the month and various (100+) difference devices.

As an example, for November I'd love to be able to see:

```
device_id      |     Utilization
A4207B23-C984     33.2
76D53271-FD34     21.9
```

Which would correspond to the 'A4' device having at least one build during 33.2% of the minutes of the month.  So November has 30 days, 24 hours, 60 minutes = 14,342 unique minutes.

Would I use something like:

```
distinct(left(build_date,16))
```

And then narrow that down by device, called by a query that uses DATEDIFF for the number of days in the month?

Any pointers or ideas would be greatly helpful.  Thanks all.  Roger

Comment: Whence is the `33.2%` coming for the first device?  I can't piece this together using only the information you gave us.

Comment: What database are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Since you refer DATEDIFF, I think you maybe using SQL Server so below is a piece of SQL that gets the total months in a minute, **you need to replace getdate() by build_date**

```
select datediff(mi, convert(varchar, datepart(mm, getdate())) + '/01/' + convert(varchar, datepart(yyyy, getdate()))
  ,eomonth(getdate())) AS MinutesInMonth
  ,device
  ,datepart(mm, getdate()) as BuildMonth
  from table
```

The next clause would get you the total active minutes in a month

```
select count(datepart(mi, getdate())) AS ActiveMinutesInAMonth
      ,datepart(mm, getdate()) as BuildMonth
      ,device          
  from table 
 group 
    by datepart(mm, getdate())
      ,device
```

Then I think it is a matter of joining the above 2 based on the device and month and dividing the latter by the former and getting your utilization.

Hope this helps